# In SQL, how do I count the number of rows showing every boolean setup possibility?

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

I currently have this dataset, intended to show every line as a potential boolean combination :

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| True | True |
| True | False |
| False | True |
| False | False |

I want this :

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | 100 |
| True | False | 50 |
| False | True | 40 |
| False | False | 10 |

Where Column_C is a COUNT(*) FROM the initial table, with conditions.

The thing is, if I use a subquery like
`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE condition) as Column_C`

I just get the total count regardless of the boolean combinations.

I get this :

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | 200 |
| True | False | 200 |
| False | True | 200 |
| False | False | 200 |

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: while you show what you want, you don't show what the rules are to get that result or what the source tables are or anything else about your database.  So there is no way to answer your question

Comment: So... there's an "initial table" somewhere that has 200 rows? Can you include a few rows of that initial table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select a, b, count(*)
from t
group by a, b;
```